# PayPal delayed chained payment - less than 90 days

Tags: php, paypal, chained-payments

I have implemented the PayPal delayed chained payment for my website but I need to have the delay only be 3 days, not the default 90 days.  Can someone please tell me if it's possible to modify the PHP script to indicate 3 days and if so tell me where in the code I make this indication.

Scenerio:  seller posts, buyer pays but has 3 days to inspect the purchase product.  If buyer is happy he can release the payment, if not happy he can indicate not to release the payment.  If buyer performs no action the payment will auto release on the 3rd day.

Using chained payment because my site gets $1 of each purchase amount.

Please let me know if delayed chained payment is the way to go with this scenario or if there is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

With a delayed chained payment in place you can trigger the secondary payments at any time using the [ExecutePayment API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/ExecutePayment_API_Operation/).

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I'm still having issues, though.  I applied the same thing today and it works, but this is the process of releasing amount to secondary user any time as said in the response.  What I'm actually looking for is a way to have the payment AUTO RELEASE in 3 days, instead of the default 90 given in the script.  This is what I'm needing help with, Auto Release in 3 days.

Comment: You can automate it with a CRON job on your server.

Comment: now I have another issue I need assistance with.  The scenario is this:  seller posts ad, buyer purchases w/ option to review purchase for 3 days. This is the DELAYED process. the monies are collected & held until release date.   If after 3 days buyer decides he doesn't like the product he can DECLINE to make payment & cancel the entire process.  If he is ok with purchase he can process payment.  so, the issue I'm having now is the DECLINE PAYMENT ability.  How is this possible if we have a cron job set up to auto release the payment in 3 days?

Comment: Add a "payment_declined" field into your database, set it to a 1 if it is declined, and then the cron job can check this field before processing payment.

Comment: OK, but the monies have been held by PayPal and are sitting in "user 1" account.  If buyer declines to finish the transaction how do we trigger PayPal to give the monies back to the buyer account?

Comment: You could use the Refund API, or you could setup Preapprovals instead of taking the money to start, and only process payments using the Preapproval when you know the transaction is complete.  That way you would avoid refunds.

Comment: Could the scenario outlined in this question be considered "aggregation" by paypal? I submitted an application for an AppId with a similar scenario and was denied on the grounds of "aggregation".

Comment: Did you make it clear you were going to be doing a delayed chained payment?  Also, did you set it up so that you were the primary receiver, or did you set it so the 3rd party merchant was the primary receiver and you were the secondary?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes, I made it clear I would be using "Delayed Chained Payments". I set it up so that I (website owner) was the primary receiver. Is this ok?

Comment: That's probably why they denied it.  You need to set it up so that you are the secondary receiver.

Comment: If we look at the original question of this post, it says "if buyer is happy, he can release the payment, if not happy...". Isn't this assuming that the payment was made to the website, and the "release" is to the 3rd party merchant (ie: website is primary, merchant is secondary)? If the website is the secondary receiver then there is no control over when to do the "releasing" because the merchant (as the primary receiver) already has the money. Am I misunderstanding something? How can I control release of payment if I (website owner) am the secondary receiver? Thanks.

Comment: What I wish to do is also outlined here: https://www.angelleye.com/how-to-integrate-paypal-adaptive-accounts-with-php/ (see comment starting: "sorry for the delay..."). Is this no longer allowed? Or is it different from what I am suggesting (website as primary and merchant as secondary)?

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to set it up that way. Could be something else about your app that they didn't like.  Did they give you any specifics about why they denied it?

Comment: No, just a 1 sentence answer specifying "aggregation". I have asked them to elaborate but haven't heard back yet. Thank you for the help. If you have any suggestions (even on how to get in touch with them - so far I've been using the "My Messages" section of the paypal-apps page) please let me know.

Comment: The status of my application is "block" and I haven't gotten a reply from them in 4 days. Do you know why this is? I have contacted the person who was reviewing my application and also sent a message to MTS but have not heard back from either.

Comment: It's tough to say.  You could always submit a fresh application and try again.

Comment: Since I'm having trouble getting approved using Delayed Chained Payments, do you know if using Mass Pay would be any different. ie: I collect money from buyers, then I do a mass pay to the seller/s...Would this be easier to get approval for? They even state in the docs that Mass Pay is intended for marketplace payouts.